# Is there a way to Connect Labwindows CVI to teststand?

Tags: c, labwindows, teststand

I'm trying to figure out how to connect my labwindows UIR to a teststand .seq file. I want the UIR to be able to read the .seq file and then display some data from the .seq file to the UIR.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with [modules](https://www.ni.com/en-us/support/documentation/supplemental/09/teststand-code-module-development-best-practices.html).

You can pass parameters from the .seq file to the module (which in your case is a CVI program).

This will allow you to easily pass data back and fourth from the sequence.  TestStand is a test execution suite so it usually makes sense to use it as your base and build modules on top of it, or just use CVI by itself.